# Finding a proof within a paper: reduced $K$-theory of Higson compactification of $[0,\infty)$ is uncountable

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Emerson and Meyer's Paper "Dualizing the Coarse Assembly Map" (2006) states the following Proposition (5.1):

*Let $X = [0,\infty)$ be the ray with its Euclidean metric coarse structure.
Then the reduced K-theory of the Higson compactification $\eta X$ of $X$ is uncountable.*

The authors state that this is proved in the paper of A. N. Dranishnikov, J. Keesling and V. V. Uspenskij entitled "On the Higson corona of
uniformly contractible spaces" (1998).

However, I cannot seem to locate this proof within the reference, which is only 13 pages long.

It is probably the case that I do not understand enough to be able to find the statement from which this Proposition follows. Would someone more knowledgeable please point me to such a statement (if it exists) within the paper of Dranishnikov et. al.?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Keesling's 1994 paper "The One-Dimensional Cech Cohomology of the Higson Compactification and Its Corona" contains the required result (Corollary 1). It may have been mis-cited.